# can't move a Slider <input type="range"> with Cypress using arrowKeys

Tags: testing, input, frontend, slider, cypress

I'm trying to implement some tests here and can't apply my logic to the input range of this website:
https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/horizontal_slider

here my code

```js
it('and a slider is displayed, the slider is moved to a specific position', () =>{
    cy.visit('/horizontal_slider')

    // to achieve this, we need to know the attributes of the slider component
    // min; max; value and step
    // we need to move the slider using the keyboard (right arrow) to move the slider
    // each type the key is pressed, the slider will move one value equal to the "step" attribute

    const destiny = 1
    const step = 0.5
    const initialValue = 0
    const stepsToReachDestiny = (destiny - initialValue) / step 

    // now we repeat x times (stepsToReachDestiny) 
    // the key press to reach the value
    const keyboardCommandRepeated = '{rightArrow}'.repeat(stepsToReachDestiny)

    // and call the function
    cy.get('.sliderContainer > input').click()

    cy.get('.sliderContainer > input').type(keyboardCommandRepeated)

    // check the value in the slider
    cy.get('.sliderContainer > span')
        .should('have.value', destiny)
})
```

The slider just does not move.
The Cypress Documentation says about using invoke() method but I rather avoid that to see the slider being moved

Comment: I know you are trying with arrow keys, have you tried using `.click()` or `.reaclClick()` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few things going on here.

The range input does not respond to Cypress' `.type('{rightArrow}')` but you can use [cypress-real-events](https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events) `.realType('{rightarrow}')` instead.

**Note** `rightarrow` instead of `rightArrow`.

Take a look at the source code, there is an `onchange` event handler to update the span.

```html
<input type="range" min="0.0" max="5.0" step="0.5" value="0" onchange="showValue(this.value)">
```

To make the span change you need to trigger this change event.

This means you can't repeat the `rightarrow`, each step will need the change event to be triggered individually.

Finally, the span has `text` not `value`.

```js
it('and a slider is displayed, the slider is moved to a specific position', () =>{
  cy.visit('https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/horizontal_slider')

  const destiny = 1
  const step = 0.5
  const initialValue = 0
  const stepsToReachDestiny = (destiny - initialValue) / step 

  cy.get('.sliderContainer > input').focus()    // use focus instead of click
  
  // loop the steps so that we can trigger change event each step
  Cypress._.times(stepsToReachDestiny, (i) => {

    const expectedAtThisStep = (i+1) * step

    cy.get('.sliderContainer > input').realType('{rightarrow}')
    cy.get('.sliderContainer > input').trigger('change')

    // check the internal value
    cy.get('.sliderContainer > input')
      .invoke('val').then(val => +val)  // get value text and convert to number
      .should('eq', expectedAtThisStep)

    // check the external span text
    cy.get('.sliderContainer > span')
      .should('have.text', expectedAtThisStep)
  })

  cy.get('.sliderContainer > span')
    .should('have.text', destiny)
})
```

Comment: Is there a faster way to adjust the slider in cypress? 
For example if you need to set slider to 75%, it would take you a long time to achieve that.

Comment: Indeed, it's an input element so you should be able to use `cy.get('input').invoke('val', '21')` - using a bit of math and trial-and-error to get to 75% mark.