# Test IonRange in Cypress

Tags: reactjs, testing, ionic-framework, range, cypress

It is interesting, that such standard behaviour in such a standard component is so hard to test.

Given an IonRange element in my Ionic React component:

```js
<IonRange
  min={0}
  max={30}
  onIonInput={()=> console.log("changed")}
/>
```

When I manually test the IonRange, I get the console output as expected.
However, when I have my cypress test like this [(pretty much copied over from the docs)](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/trigger#Interact-with-a-range-input-slider):

```js
cy.get("ion-range")
  .as('range')
  .invoke('val', 10)
  .trigger('change')
```

I expect to see the log statement in the output.

Actual behaviour: the range knob jumps to the expected position but the `onIonInout` callback is never invoked.

I also tried other triggers, such as

```js
  .trigger('ion-change')
  .trigger('input')
  .trigger('ion-input')
  .trigger('range-change')
  .trigger('ionChange')
  .trigger('ionInput')
```

all leading to the same behaviour.

I also tried to workaround using arrow keys.
That would be a very unsatisfying solution, because it does not generalise for cases with ranges of, say, 0 to 10,000. I tried it anyway:

```js
cy.get("ion-range").type('{rightArrow}') // trows "this is a non-typable element"
```

The range knob jumps to the centre (weirdly).

The workaround that I ended up with is:

```js
cy.get("ion-range").click() // clicks in the centre
```

(also mentioned by @SuchAnIgnorantThingToDo-UKR)
and then I expect the value 15. But due to differences in rendering resolutions (even with a set viewport), the result flakes between 15 and 16. Also, this solution is very unsatisfying given we might want to assert for specific values)

I reviewed the following:

- [This article is not helpful since I'm already using a plain number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55023428/how-do-interact-correctly-with-a-range-input-slider-in-cypress)
- [And this is kinda related but a different special case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72214974/cant-move-a-slider-input-type-range-with-cypress-using-arrowkeys)

Please let me know if you have any idea for this very trivial every-day problem.

Comment: Find the input field(typeable) element in the IonRange component and type into that element. 

Same goes for the `.trigger` part. It needs to be done on a 'changeable' element.

Comment: @DarkoRiđić, can you maybe provide a one-line  example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@SuchAnIgnorantThingToDo-UKR already answered in great detail.

I just want to add how to test the dragging. You can do this:

```js
describe('Components', () => {
  it('ion-range', () => {
    cy.visit('https://ionicframework.com/docs/usage/v7/range/basic/demo.html?ionic:mode=ios')

    cy.get('ion-range').as('slider')

    const waitTime = 200

    cy.get('@slider') //
      .trigger('mouseenter')
      .wait(waitTime)
      .trigger('mousedown', 100, 0)
      .wait(waitTime)
      .trigger('mousemove', 150, 1, { force: true })
      .wait(waitTime)
      .trigger('mousemove', 200, 1, { force: true })
      .wait(waitTime)
      .trigger('mousemove', 300, 1, { force: true })
      .wait(waitTime)
      .trigger('mouseup', 300, 1)
  })
})
```

Comment: Hey @Darko, thanks for your input. I understand the waitTime is just for demonstration. While this does work it's not 100% robust. As soon as I change the view port aspect ratio, this will fail. It's a good workaround for now though. So thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `.click()` command will alter the value and trigger the event handler, however it's not as precise as setting the value directly.

```js
cy.window()
  .its('console')
  .then((console) => {
    cy.spy(console, 'log').as('log')
  })

cy.get('ion-range')
  .click(300,0)

cy.get('@log') 
  .should('have.been.calledWith', 'changed', 31)
  .invoke('getCalls')
  .then((calls) => {
    // open the DevTools to see the dumped table
    console.table(calls)
    expect(calls[0].args).to.deep.eq(['changed', 31]) // not exact, a +1 pixel occurs
  })
```

from

```html
<IonRange onIonChange={({ detail })=> console.log("changed", detail.value)}></IonRange>
```

The IonRange seems to have a different internal mechanism to the two linked examples you cited.

Those have an `<input>` underlying, but IonRange does not have one. Instead, it's a stencil based web component which responds the events in it's own particular way.

---

**The range knob jumps to the centre (weirdly)**

I got the same with `.click()` but not specifying the coordinates to click at. I think that's because the `.type()` has a `.click()` built in.

The default click position, if not specified, is the center of the element.

Comment: yeah, I tried the click, but as you say it is unsatisfyingly imprecise

Comment: ok, now I had time to read through your answer in detail. Even tough it does not solve the exact problem, I still learned a lot. 

I would always want to avoid cy commands that depend on px values, because I don't want my test suit to break when I decide to change the viewport target.